# JSON, Retrofit 2 and converters on Android

Tags: android, json, converters, retrofit, mvp

I'm trying to use Retrofit to get data from an exchange rate [remote API](https://apilayer.com/).

Just for more precision, I don't ask how to return an arraylist... I just want to know if it's better to return an arraylist or use a Retrofit converter and if a retrofit converter suits this kind of situation.

This API returns me a JSON formatted like this :

```
{
  "success": true,
  "terms": "https://currencylayer.com/terms",
  "privacy": "https://currencylayer.com/privacy",
  "timestamp": 1487243354,
  "source": "USD",
  "quotes": {
    "USDAED": 3.672503,
    "USDAFN": 66.599998,
    "USDALL": 127.501996,
    "USDAMD": 486.119995,
    "USDANG": 1.769648,
    "USDAOA": 165.082001,
    "USDARS": 15.37279,
    "USDAUD": 1.299101,
    "USDAWG": 1.8017,
    "USDAZN": 1.729104,
    "USDBAM": 1.842499,
    "USDBBD": 2,
    "USDBDT": 79.249746,
    "USDBGN": 1.853047,
    ...
    }
}
```

I used this website [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to create my object from the JSON data. It created me two classes `Example` and `Quotes`. My `Quotes` class look like this :

```
public class Quotes {

    @SerializedName("USDAED")
    @Expose
    private Double uSDAED;
    @SerializedName("USDAFN")
    @Expose
    private Double uSDAFN;
    @SerializedName("USDALL")
    @Expose
    private Double uSDALL;
    @SerializedName("USDAMD")
    @Expose
    private Double uSDAMD;
    @SerializedName("USDANG")
    @Expose
    private Double uSDANG;
    @SerializedName("USDAOA")
    ...
}
```

The `Example` class only contains one method to retrieve the `Quotes` called getQuotes() returning a Quotes object with all the quotes. Then I have to call a getter() of my `Quotes` class to get an exchange rate. The thing is I would like to to have a methods that returns me all the quotes in a list and don't have to call all the getters... Sure I can do this easily modifying the method in my `Example` class or in different other way. Anyway I would like to know what would be the best way to do this, I mean in terms of good practices, I use MVP architecture with Dagger 2. I heard about custom converter with Retrofit, could it be useful and appropriate in this specific case ? by the way if you have a good (understandable) link about Retrofit custom converter feel free to share... I'm doing this project for educational purpose so please don't propose me another API, I want to achieve it like this, with this API.

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
    @SerializedName("terms")
    @Expose
    private String terms;
    @SerializedName("privacy")
    @Expose
    private String privacy;
    @SerializedName("timestamp")
    @Expose
    private Integer timestamp;
    @SerializedName("source")
    @Expose
    private String source;
    @SerializedName("quotes")
    @Expose
    private Quotes quotes;

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getTerms() {
        return terms;
    }

    public void setTerms(String terms) {
        this.terms = terms;
    }

    public String getPrivacy() {
        return privacy;
    }

    public void setPrivacy(String privacy) {
        this.privacy = privacy;
    }

    public Integer getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Integer timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public Quotes getQuotes() {
        return quotes;
    }

    public void setQuotes(Quotes quotes) {
        this.quotes = quotes;
    }

}
```

Comment: post your example class too.

Comment: Hey if you want all the entries within your quotes as an arrayList, why don't you just change your quotes object to be an arrayList of string. I am talking about restructuring your JSON structure to start with. That way you won't need a custom adapter or something

Comment: it cannot be  *an arrayList of string*  it is map

Comment: Just added my example class. As I wrote I use Retrofit framework. As I wrote in my questions sure I could just change my method to have an Arraylist but I just would want to know if it's the best way to do it, like better to use a Retrofit converter. I don't ask how to resolve this on an easy way but in the right way, if the right way is to return a list I can do it. But I just want to know if it is the best one. Better use the best practices now I'm just starting with this Retrofit  than doing some fast code and put a mess everywhere if i a use a same bad way to do things in a bigger project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up with the easiest solution, since nobody answered me about Retrofit converter and I had down votes I guess my question was stupid.

I used a custom Quote class instead of a HashMap just in case I want to add further informations to my Class later.

```
public class Quotes {

    @SerializedName("USDAED")
    @Expose
    private Double uSDAED;
    @SerializedName("USDAFN")
    @Expose
    private Double uSDAFN;
    @SerializedName("USDALL")
    @Expose
    private Double uSDALL;
    ...
     public List<Quote> getAllQuotes() {
        List<Quote> allQuotes = new ArrayList<>();

        allQuotes.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                new Quote("USDAED", new BigDecimal(uSDAED, MathContext.DECIMAL32)),
                new Quote("USDAFN", new BigDecimal(uSDAFN, MathContext.DECIMAL32)),
                new Quote("USDALL", new BigDecimal(uSDALL, MathContext.DECIMAL32)),
                new Quote("USDAMD", new BigDecimal(uSDAMD, MathContext.DECIMAL32)),
        ...
        new Quote("USDZMW", new BigDecimal(uSDZMW, MathContext.DECIMAL32)))

        );
        return allQuotes;
    }
    ...
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((App) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);

        String apiKey = getResources().getString(R.string.API_KEY);
        Call<Example> call = apiLayerForexAPI.getQuotes(apiKey);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
                List<Quote> allQuotes = response.body().getQuotes().getAllQuotes();
                for(Quote q : allQuotes){
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, q.toString());
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```